Elementor Nested Carousel widget with remote buttons
I want to make it go to a specific slide after clicking a specific button.
I am using the following code.
<script>
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.slide-control');

    buttons.forEach(button => {
        button.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
            const slideIndex = parseInt(event.target.getAttribute('data-slide'), 10);

            // Log the slideIndex for debugging
            console.log('Button clicked. Slide index:', slideIndex);

            // Select the swiper container
            const carousel = document.querySelector('.elementor-widget-swiper-container .swiper-container');

            // Check if the carousel and swiper instance are found
            if (carousel) {
                console.log('Swiper container found:', carousel);

                if (carousel.swiper) {
                    console.log('Swiper instance found:', carousel.swiper);
                    carousel.swiper.slideTo(slideIndex - 1); // Swiper uses 0-based index
                } else {
                    console.error('Swiper instance not found on:', carousel);
                }
            } else {
                console.error('Swiper container not found. Ensure the selector is correct.');
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>

and the following for buttons
<button class="slide-control" data-slide="1">Slide 1</button>
<button class="slide-control" data-slide="2">Slide 2</button>
<button class="slide-control" data-slide="3">Slide 3</button>

But it doesn't work
